# Как исправить ошибку failed target android-23?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

получил ошибку:

> Gradle 'first' project refresh failed
>
> Error: failed to find target with hash string 'andorid-23' in C:\Users\Den\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>
> Install missing platform(s) and sync project

клик по ссылке не срабатывает

в sdk необходимая версия стоит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Либо что-то с правами на папки, либо просто удалите и поставьте SDK 23 заново.

Comment: И еще проверьте что за build tools используются в проекте. Кстати, старые с номером < 25.0.0 можете удалить.

Comment: где посмотреть build tools используемые в проекте?

Comment: В build.gradle модуля. А SDK у Вас точно в той папке, что указана в ошибке?

Comment: спасибо, появился диалог `UPDATE` и ошибка исчезла